# Is there a way to optimize shared_ptr for the case of permanent objects?

Tags: c++, optimization, shared-ptr

I've got some code that is using `shared_ptr` quite widely as the standard way to refer to a particular type of object (let's call it `T`) in my app.  I've tried to be careful to use `make_shared` and `std::move` and `const T&` where I can for efficiency.  Nevertheless, my code spends a great deal of time passing `shared_ptr`s around (the object I'm wrapping in `shared_ptr` is the central object of the whole caboodle).  The kicker is that pretty often the `shared_ptr`s are pointing to an object that is used as a marker for "no value"; this object is a global instance of a particular `T` subclass, and it lives forever since its refcount never goes to zero.

Using a "no value" object is nice because it responds in nice ways to various methods that get sent to these objects, behaving in the way that I want "no value" to behave.  However, performance metrics indicate that a huge amount of the time in my code is spent incrementing and decrementing the refcount of that global singleton object, making new `shared_ptr`s that refer to it and then destroying them.  To wit: for a simple test case, the execution time went from 9.33 seconds to 7.35 seconds if I stuck `nullptr` inside the `shared_ptr`s to indicate "no value", instead of making them point to the global singleton `T` "no value" object.  That's a hugely important difference; run on much larger problems, this code will soon be used to do multi-day runs on computing clusters.  So I really need that speedup.  But I'd really like to have my "no value" object, too, so that I don't have to put checks for `nullptr` all over my code, special-casing that possibility.

So.  Is there a way to have my cake and eat it too?  In particular, I'm imagining that I might somehow subclass `shared_ptr` to make a "shared_immortal_ptr" class that I could use with the "no value" object.  The subclass would act just like a normal `shared_ptr`, but it would simply never increment or decrement its refcount, and would skip all related bookkeeping.  Is such a thing possible?

I'm also considering making an inline function that would do a `get()` on my `shared_ptr`s and would substitute a pointer to the singleton immortal object if `get()` returned `nullptr`; if I used that everywhere in my code, and never used `*` or `->` directly on my `shared_ptr`s, I would be insulated, I suppose.

Or is there another good solution for this situation that hasn't occurred to me?

Comment: I would consider whether all your copies need to be shared pointers. Only the objects or scopes that `own` the resource need to be shared pointers, calls *down* to functions within those scopes can be made with the raw pointer safe in the knowledge that the owning shared pointer will outlive the call.

Comment: **see:** https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r32-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics

Comment: Btw, have you measured in debug or release mode? I remember that I have seen a huge performance difference with smart pointers, but this was a couple of years ago. It may be that most of the function calls just were inlined, and thus no copies were made anymore.

Comment: @Galik, yes, I'm trying hard to use `const T&` when I can, such as in calls down to functions that do not need to share ownership.  The big problem is that new `shared_ptr`s are typically created deep down in a recursive call hierarchy and then need to get passed out, and as far as I can tell each return of a `shared_ptr` out to a caller is resulting in a refcount inc/dec; the compiler is *not* optimizing those away with move semantics or whatever, the way I would expect.  I tried doing `return std::move(x)` instead of just `return x` but (unsurprisingly) it did not help.

Comment: @Jens, these measurements are on a Release mode build in Xcode on OS X; I don't think any debug-mode code is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galik asked the central question that comes to mind regarding your containment strategy. I'll assume you've considered that and have reason to rely on shared_ptr as a communical containment strategy for which no alternative exists.

I have to suggestions which may seem controversial. What you've defined is that you need a type of shared_ptr that never has a nullptr, but `std::shared_ptr` doesn't do that, and I checked various versions of the STL to confirm that the customer deleter provided is not an entry point to a solution.

So, consider either making your own smart pointer, or adopting one that you change to suit your needs. The basic idea is to establish a kind of shared_ptr which can be instructed to point it's shadow pointer to a global object it doesn't own.

You have the source to `std::shared_ptr`. The code is uncomfortable to read. It may be difficult to work with. It is one avenue, but of course you'd copy the source, change the namespace and implement the behavior you desire.

However, one of the first things all of us did in the middle 90's when templates were first introduced to the compilers of the epoch was to begin fashioning containers and smart pointers. Smart pointers are remarkably easy to write. They're harder to design (or were), but then you have a design to model (which you've already used).

You can implement the basic interface of shared_ptr to create a drop in replacement. If you used typedefs well, there should be a limited few places you'd have to change, but at least a search and replace would work reasonably well.

These are the two means I'm suggesting, both ending up with the same feature. Either adopt shared_ptr from the library, or make one from scratch. You'd be surprised how quickly you can fashion a replacement.

If you adopt `std::shared_ptr`, the main theme would be to understand how shared_ptr determines it should decrement. In most implementations shared_ptr must reference a node, which in my version it calls a control block (_Ref). The node owns the object to be deleted when the reference count reaches zero, but naturally shared_ptr skips that if _Ref is null. However, operators like -> and *, or the get function, don't bother checking _Ref, they just return the shadow, or _Ptr in my version.

Now, _Ptr will be set to nullptr (or 0 in my source) when a reset is called. Reset is called when assigning to another object or pointer, so this works even if using assignment to nullptr. The point is, that for this new type of shared_ptr you need, you could simply change the behavior such that whenever that happens (a reset to nullptr), you set _Ptr, the shadow pointer in shared_ptr, to the "no value global" object's address.

All uses of *,get or -> will return the _Ptr of that no value object, and will correctly behave when used in another assignment, or reset is called again, because those functions don't rely upon the shadow pointer to act upon the node, and since in this special condition that node (or control block) will be nullptr, the rest of shared_ptr would behave as though it was pointing to nullptr correctly - that is, not deleting the global object.

Obviously this sounds crazy to alter `std::pointer` to such application specific behavior, but frankly that's what performance work tends to make us do; otherwise strange things, like abandoning C++ occasionally in order to obtain the more raw speed of C, or assembler.

Modifying `std::shared_ptr` source, taken as a copy for this special purpose, is not what I would choose (and, factually, I've faced other versions of your situation, so I have made this choice several times over decades).

To that end, I suggest you build a policy based smart pointer. I find it odd I suggested this earlier on another post today (or yesterday, it's 1:40am).

I refer to Alexandrescu's book from 2001 (I think it was Modern C++...and some words I don't recall). In that he presented loki, which included a policy based smart pointer design, which is still published and freely available on his website.

The idea should have been incorporated into shared_ptr, in my opinion.

Policy based design is implemented as the paradigm of a template class deriving from one or more of it's parameters, like this:

```
template< typename T, typename B >
class TopClass : public B {};
```

In this way, you can provide B, from which the object is built. Now, B may have the same construction, it may also be a policy level which derives from it's second parameter (or multiple derivations, however the design works).

Layers can be combined to implement unique behaviors in various categories.

For example:

`std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`are separate classes which interact as a family with others (the nodes or control blocks) to provide smart pointer service. However, in a design I used several times, these two were built by the same top level template class. The difference between a shared_ptr and a weak_ptr in that design was the attachment policy offered in the second parameter to the template. If the type is instantiated with the weak attachment policy as the second parameter, it's a weak pointer. If it's given a strong attachment policy, it's a smart pointer.

Once you create a policy designed template, you can introduce layers not in the original design (expanding it), or to "intercept" behavior and specialize it like the one you currently require - without corrupting the original code or design.

The smart pointer library I developed had high performance requirements, along with a number of other options including custom memory allocation and automatic locking services to make writing to smart pointers thread safe (which `std::shared_ptr` doesn't provide). The interface and much of the code is shared, yet several different kinds of smart pointers could be fashioned simply by selecting different policies. To change behavior, a new policy could be inserted without altering the existing code. At present, I use both std::shared_ptr (which I used when it was in boost years ago) and the MetaPtr library I developed years ago, the latter when I need high performance or flexible options, like yours.

If std::shared_ptr had been a policy based design, as loki demonstrates, you'd be able to do this with shared_ptr WITHOUT having to copy the source and move it to a new namespace.

In any event, simply creating a shared pointer which points the shadow pointer to the global object on reset to nullptr, leaving the node pointing to null, provides the behavior you described.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.  I'm hesitant to mark it as accepted, because I'm unlikely to pursue it – I just don't have the C++ chops.  The intricacies of things like move semantics are things I still struggle with; just trying to use `shared_ptr` as a client is pushing me to the edge of my comfort zone, so trying to write my own just seems crazy.  The code I'm working on needs to be cross-platform, too, which makes it much harder; I could copy and modify the `shared_ptr` on my platform, but that might work poorly on other platforms.  But if nobody has a better solution, I'll accept.

Comment: Really I was hoping there would be a way to subclass `shared_ptr` to achieve this.  At least I'd like to subclass it to simply disable the `*` and `->` operators, to force all use of these `shared_ptr`s in my code to be done through a custom `get()` that could substitute a standard pointer in place of `nullptr`, as I mentioned in my question.  But I take it `shared_ptr` is not subclassable?

Comment: Well, you can subclass but you need access to _Ptr, an internal data member representing the shadow pointer, and it's private. So while you can subclass, you can't achieve the objective. Frankly, changing a copy of shared_ptr is actually trivial work. You'd be done in two hours finding your way in the dark. I could do it in about 10 minutes, but I've been at this 30+ years. You really only need to change the reset function (everything you need wires through it). Where it sets _Ptr to 0 (or nullptr), just change that to your "no value" object's address, and you could test it right then.

Comment: Further, if you took boosts source instead (which is where both TR1 and std::shared_ptr were taken), you have a portable version that would work on anything from Windows to Linux to iOS and Android.

Comment: interesting.  I'll take a look at the Boost source and see if I can make head or tail of it.  It is all C++11ified to take advantage of move semantics etc., then?  I knew it was the ancestor of `shared_ptr`, but since it predates C++11, I was not sure how smart/modern it was under the hood.

Comment: As it turns out, Boost's intrusive_ptr looks like it can be easily adapted to my needs, and its code is quite readily understandable.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  I have hesitated to get into Boost because I don't want to have the added link dependency; but it looks quite simple to rip intrusive_ptr out of Boost to make it a source file in my own project.

Comment: I'm glad that worked out, and thanks. I'm surprised at your choice only because I had assumed you'd opt for something with less of an impact on existing code, but then that wasn't a stipulation either, it was an assumption I made. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90644/discussion-between-bhaller-and-jvene).